# Q: Exception in executing publishing: Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader' threw an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded from VS2015 Update 2 to VS2015 Update 3.

I went to my web project and clicked `Publish...`

This window appeared.

[image]

I've tried deleting my publish profiles, but the same error happens.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close down visual studio and re-open the project.

You may also experience a message about the treeview control when you go to File->New Project.

Restarting VS2015 cures both problems.